# Minhash Jaccard to find similarity between documents

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, data-mining

I wrote a program to check the similarity of 40 documents. Firstly i use exact Jaccard method and secondly Minhash Jaccard method. I consider that the 2 methods differ if their values are differ more than 0,1. I also run the program for permutations 10,40,100,200,450. Which Jaccard limit must i choose to consider 2 documents as similar?

Comment: It's up to you – there's no standard value.

Comment: ok thank you. And something else, if i choose bigger numbers for permutation will i get more accurate results about the documents similarity?